# Georeference to UTM projection using openlayers plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I have some aerial imagery that I need to georeference using QGIS into a UTM projection.  In order to do this I need a basemap layer for the reference points.  The openlayers plugin could work great for this but it's in the web Mercator projection.  I attempted to georeference to the Web Mercator projection and then use the warp tool to transform to NAD 83 UTM but it doesn't seem to transform correctly.  Should my process here work and I'm just missing a setting or step, or should I be going about this a different route all together?

Comment: Your workflow should be right. Is the georeferenced raster (before transforming) well-aligned to the openlayers background?

Comment: Thanks for confirmation.  I tried it again and have it working now.  I was mistaking not keeping it in the Web Mercator projection when I was loading the image into the georeferencer.  I'm all good now.